# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" in angular

Tags: angular, forms

when I create a form in angular it shows me that error but I already include forms module in my module file. Here is my code and error

html

```
<form #ProfileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getValue(ProfileForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <h3>Add Your Personal Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" ngModel name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
    </div>
</form
```

module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class FormModule { }
```

error

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<div class="body">
  <form [ERROR ->]#ProfileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getValue(ProfileForm.value)">
```

Comment: Can you post your real `declarations: [],`?

Comment: empty one , i am new in angular so i don't have much idea  @kvetis

Comment: Would be more help if you shared your module and component structure, but I tried to guess two cases that the structure can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `FormsModule` in the module where the component with the form is declared, not in the `FormModule` you showed us.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponentWithForm],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ]
})
export class MyOtherModule { }
```

Or if you're importing the `FormModule` into the module where your component is declared, you need to re-export the module you're interested in in order for the directives the `FormsModule` includes to work inside your component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class FormModule { }
```

Comment: ok solved my issue by importing formmodule in my app.module file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code?

Create form in component.html file using FormGroup

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="getValue(ProfileForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <h3>Add Your Personal Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
    </div>
</form>
```

And in your component.ts file

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

And above constructor put below code

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('')
});
```

For your reference check [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) link

Comment: still giving error    Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Comment: can you please import in app.module.ts file?

Comment: import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms' and put in the imports section FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule. in app.module.ts file

Comment: Got it what I am saying?

Comment: already import formsmodule and reactiveformmodule in module.ts file check my question

Comment: Yes I have checked but you are imported in form.module.ts file can you please import in app.module.ts file?

Comment: yeah thanks it works after importing in module.ts file

Comment: Can you please mark as right if solution is perfect working?